# MAGENTO ERROR: PayPal gateway rejected the request. Not signed up for this tender type

Tags: magento

Using Magento 1.8 and on the shopping cart page when you try to continue with paypal its supposed to redirect but this error pops up: PayPal gateway rejected the request. Not signed up for this tender type

Any Ideas how to fix this??

Comment: Are you using PayPal express or Payment Pro?

Comment: Just checked we are using PayPal express. Any help is appreciated. Someone else set it up so not sure what is missing or wrong. thanks

Comment: Can you verify that you are not in Sandbox mode?

Comment: If you are not in sanbox mode, you'll need to check all of you paypal settings.  PayPal is usually glad tyo help with this...Here is a quide with the PayPal support number at the top of the page http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-paypal-express-checkout-for-magento-community

Comment: Correct sandbox mode: NO, That error happens right at the moment the site tries to redirect to paypal website. I noticed in the Paypal express checkout section in admin configure is grayed out, but in paypal gateways, payflow pro express has the green check mark is configurable. Must be something in there. Thanks for the link

Comment: did you get the answer

Answer (score 0):

look this  answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29354/payflow-percentage-discount-issue. Change Classes from Mage.

```
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3udWHRsbBdAOEpPSmJocXA1TFE/edit?pli=1
```